# How to resize image before uploading it ?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, image-resizing

In my AIR app, the user can take a photo (from CameraRoll or CameraUI) and save it to a server.

Is there a way to automatically resize the image (800x600) in order to have a lighter file ?

Here's my code :

```
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var saveDirectory:String= "MyApp/PhotoUploads";
    var fileName:String = "MyPhoto" + now.fullYear + now.month + now.day + now.hours + now.minutes + now.seconds + ".jpg";
    var photoFile:File=File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(saveDirectory+"/"+ fileName);

 function imageSelected( event:MediaEvent ):void{
    var mp:MediaPromise = event.data;

dataSource = mp.open();
 readMediaData();
}


function readMediaData():void{

    var imageBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
     dataSource.readBytes( imageBytes );
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.addEventListener( Event.CLOSE,photoFileSaved);
    stream.openAsync( photoFile,FileMode.WRITE); 
    stream.writeBytes( imageBytes );
    stream.close();
    }    

 function photoFileSaved(evt:Event):void{
     photoUpload();
 }

 function photoUpload():void{
     photoFile.upload( req );
     photoFile.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress_func );
     photoFile.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorMedia );
     photoFile.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, complete_func );
 }
```

Apparently I can't do :

```
mp.width = 200;
mp.height= 200;
```

So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scale:Number = .6;

var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.scale (scale,scale);

var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sourceMc.width, sourceMc.height, false);
bmp.draw (sourceMc,m);
```

Comment: `sourceMc` is `photoFile` ?

Comment: I'm, indeed, looking what `sourceMc` is, in order to do  `sourceMc.width`

Comment: I'm wondering if, by "SourceMc" you meant MovieClip. If so, my image isn't display in a movieClip.

Comment: Yes sourceMc to get your img size. You don't have to if you already know the size. If you don't, place the img in a tmp movieclip to get its size.............................